# Successfully installed Mongodb driver and getting MongoClient class not found error

Tags: php, mongodb

I have successfully installed Mongodb driver and updated the `php.ini` file at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` with the following line:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

[image: Output of phpinfo()]

And I have the following code:

```
<?php m = new MongoClient(); ?>
```

And getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: is your Mongo instance is running while connecting it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation mentioned here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php, the `MongoClient` class is deprecated.

Instead try this: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php.

Comment: Thanks. This one's API is nicer than writing raw JavaScript code :)

Comment: @MustafaShujaie: If this solves your problem, mind to mark it as answer?